# Allowing unsafe/restricted ports for CEF

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I'm currently using CefSharp in an application and trying to load a web page hosted on port 6668 and the web page is unable to load but hosting the web page on a port chromium doesn't consider unsafe works.

[List of restricted chrome ports](https://superuser.com/questions/188058/which-ports-are-considered-unsafe-on-chrome)

For chrome there is a command line arg for explicitly allowing unsafe ports

ex: chrome.exe --explicitly-allowed-ports=81,84,87

However I don't see any information that says CEF supports or doesn't support this command line argument or has a way to allow unsafe ports.

I've tried adding the argument before initialization but it still doesn't allow the port. I've also tried putting a "-" or "--" before explicitly-allowed-ports just to test it in the example below but neither work. Not including the preceding -'s seems to be correct from looking at the [CefSharp example](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Example/CefExample.cs) as well.

```
var settings = new CefSettings();
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("explicitly-allowed-ports", "6000,6665,6666,6667,6668,6669");
Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

Is there another way to allow restricted ports for CEF or does CEF just not support this command line arg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like CEF would need to be patched to make the `net::SetExplicitlyAllowedPorts` call in the browser process. See https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/ui/startup/startup_browser_creator.cc?l=593&rcl=e756eda1d880f2481c88b1e599963e8f46b8b485 .